# How to enable Steam overlay while playing Dungeons of Dredmor?

Tags: steam, dungeons-of-dredmor

For some reasons I cannot access to Steam overlay and other Steam features (F12->screenshot) while playing Dungeons of Dredmor. Do you know how to fix it?

Just to be precise the in-game option in the Steam game properties is enabled.

Comment: They carefully say in the description of the Steam overlay "In most games" - maybe it just doesn't support it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As written [here](http://www.gaslampgames.com/blog/2011/07/14/crashes-cynical-brit-feature-request-faq/) by developers is a known bug.

> Steam Overlay: Looking in to this one. It’d be quite ideal to get this
>   working.

**Update:** It will be fixed in next patch.

> Yes! Steam overlay now confirmed to be working with the latest patch. ([tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/GaslampGames/status/93124946867400704))

When the patch 1.0.3 will be live add `-opengl` to Steam launch parameters to enable Steam overlay (experimental)

Answer (score 0):

In the first post on [this](http://neogaf.net/forum/showthread.php?t=435078&page=88) page  says specifically that it crashes in fullscreen. Have you tried pressing shift-tab when you were not in fullscreen?

This would only be a temporary solution, but it has been reported [here](http://www.gaslampgames.com/forum/search?Search=overlay) on the developer's support site as a bug, so it may be fixed in the future.